# Creating a label in all my views in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new at objective c and I need some help to create a label which appears in all my ViewControllers with the same text but this text will be changed constantly.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Category class for this

## in .h File

```
//
//  UILabel+withString.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UILabel (withString)

+ (UILabel *)labelWithString:(NSString *)string
                    font:(UIFont *)font
                   color:(UIColor *)color
               container:(CGRect)container
                  origin:(CGPoint)origin;

@end
```

## In .m File

```
//
//  UILabel+withString.m
//

 #import "UILabel+withString.h"


 @implementation UILabel (withString)

 + (UILabel *)labelWithString:(NSString *)string
                    font:(UIFont *)font
                   color:(UIColor *)color
               container:(CGRect)container
                  origin:(CGPoint)origin {
 CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:container.size
    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

 UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, container.size.width, size.height)] autorelease];
 label.text = string;
 label.font = font;
 label.textColor = color;
 label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
 label.numberOfLines = 1;
 label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 return label;
 }

 @end
```

then in view controller you can call this

Comment: this way my label will appear in differents ViewController?

Comment: Yup just you have to import this file

Comment: how can i call it in my view controller?

Comment: no, i know objective c, the prolem is that i dont speak english

Comment: You are developer,you should have to learn English first,lol ,i specified answer 90% i reduce your efforts now 10% do it own